# Vectorised solution to fill rows of a column based on value from previous row in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

Dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"X":[1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]})

print(df)
     X
0  1.0
1  NaN
2  NaN
3  NaN
4  NaN
5  NaN
```

I want to populate np.nan by taking squares of values from previous row and adding one to it.

Desired output:

```
         X
0       1.0
1       2.0
2       5.0
3      26.0
4     677.0
5  458330.0
```

This can be done by a for loop with:

```
for i in range(1,len(df)):
    df["X"].iloc[i] = ((df["X"].iloc[i-1]) ** 2) + 1
```

But looking for a vectorised solution of the same problem

Comment: It cannot be done using vectorized approach because you are operating at one row at a time. It is impossible to know the value of 5th element without all preceders, hence you do need to iterate. If you use listcomp it should be faster

Comment: Starting from `i=7` the numbers `a[i]` and `a[i]+1` are indistinguishable (with double precision), so you could just compute `a[7+i] = a[7] ** (2**i)`.

Comment: `numpy.ufunc` have a `accumulate` method (e.g. `cumsum`) but they harder to use in a composite way thanthe parallel elementwise versions.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately vecorized solution is problematic, because is used previous output value. For improve performance is used [**numba**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#using-numba):

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def f(a):
    for i in range(1, a.shape[0]):
        a[i] = a[i-1] ** 2 + 1
    return a

df['X'] = f(df['X'].to_numpy())
print (df)
                X
0    1.000000e+00
1    2.000000e+00
2    5.000000e+00
3    2.600000e+01
4    6.770000e+02
5    4.583300e+05
6    2.100664e+11
7    4.412789e+22
8    1.947270e+45
9    3.791862e+90
10  1.437822e+181
```